# Calculating a max for every X number of lines, how to take leap year into account?

Tags: python, for-loop, lines, leap-year

I am trying to take yearly max rainfall data for multiple years of data within one array. I understand how you would need to use a for loop if I wanted to take the max of a single range, I saw there was similar question to the problem I'm having. However, I need to take leap year into account!

So for the first year I have 14616 data points from 1960-1965, not including 1965, which contains 2 leap years: 1960 and 1964. A leap year contains 2928 data points and every other year contains 2920 data points.

I first thought was to modify the solution from the similar question which involved using a for loop as follows (just a straight copy paste from their's):

```
for i,d in enumerate(data_you_want):
    if (i % 600) == 0:
        avg_for_day = np.mean(data_you_want[i - 600:i])
        daily_averages.append(avg_for_day)
```

Their's involved taking the average of every 600 lines in their data. I thought there might be a way to just modify this, but I couldn't figure out a way for it to work. If modification of this won't work, is there another way to loop it with the leap years taken into account without completely cutting up the file manually.

Comment: what does your raw data look like? show us a sample.

Comment: It is rather unclear what you are asking: you want a max for every x number of lines? every x number of days? every x numbers of data points? every fixed period in time for every year, accounting for leap years? 
Can you clarify please?

Comment: So I'm looking for the maximum value of each year spanning over 5 full years with 8 data points per day. I need a not so tedious way to get the max for each year that take the leap years, that extra 8 data points, into account.

Comment: Also it's in a 1D array with a shape of (14616L,) and actually data is along these lines for values: [  2.58524706e-05   2.60845190e-05   2.70563996e-05 ...,   2.66889438e-052.48712859e-05   2.37914537e-05]

Comment: What is the array's datatype?  Is it a numpy ndarray?.

Comment: It's a numpy array

Answer (score 1):

Fake data:

```
import numpy as np
fake = np.random.randint(2, 30, size = 14616)
```

Use pandas to handle the leap year functionality.

Create timestamps for your data with [`pandas.date_range()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html).

```
import pandas as pd
index = pd.date_range(start = '1960-1-1 00:00:00', end = '1964-12-31 23:59:59' , freq='3H')
```

Then create a DataFrame using the timestamps for the index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = fake, index = index)
```

Aggregate by year - taking advantage of the [DatetimeIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#indexing) flexibilty.

```
>>> df['1960'].max()
0    29
dtype: int32
>>> df['1960'].mean()
0    15.501366
dtype: float64
>>> 

>>> len(df['1960'])
2928
>>> len(df['1961'])
2920
>>> len(df['1964'])
2928
>>>
```

---

I just cobbled this together from the [Time Series / Date functionality](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#) section of the docs.  Given pandas capability this looks a bit naive and probably can be improved upon.

Like [resampling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) (using the same DataFrame)

```
>>> df.resample('A').mean()
                    0
1960-12-31  15.501366
1961-12-31  15.170890
1962-12-31  15.412329
1963-12-31  15.538699
1964-12-31  15.382514
>>> df.resample('A').max()
             0
1960-12-31  29
1961-12-31  29
1962-12-31  29
1963-12-31  29
1964-12-31  29
>>>

>>> r = df.resample('A')
>>> r.agg([np.sum, np.mean, np.std])
                0                     
              sum       mean       std
1960-12-31  45388  15.501366  8.211835
1961-12-31  44299  15.170890  8.117072
1962-12-31  45004  15.412329  8.257992
1963-12-31  45373  15.538699  7.986877
1964-12-31  45040  15.382514  8.178057
>>>
```

---

Food for thought:
[Time-aware Rolling vs. Resampling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#stats-moments-ts-versus-resampling)